# Move the post title to another field

Tags: custom-field, title

i added a new field (property_second) to the admin area of the theme. and i want this field value to be the same as the post title. so if the post title changes, let it change here. how can I do it?

```
array(
            'key' => ERE_METABOX_PREFIX. 'property_second',
            'value' => $keyword,
            'type' => 'CHAR',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
```

Comment: Are you asking how to store the post title in a meta field, or how to update that meta field if/when the post title changes?

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the post status transitions and copy the post title to your secondary field. See documentation:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions#transition_post_status_Hook